# What is the best practice to enable ssl in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat, ssl

I have a spring boot application that will be deployed in multiple servers. I have the jks file for each server in the classpath. What is the best way to streamline the deployment?  I would prefer not to pass the name of the jks file in the command line along with the profile name.

Comment: I would deploy the app as a `war` file. Then enable `https` on `tomcat`, i.e, modify `server.xml` to include the keystore . That way I have more control on my apps.

Answer (score 1):

Just add these properties in your existing application.properties .

```
server.ssl.key-store: keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: mypassword
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is that I have different certificate for each server and the alias is the same.